# Select2: Display all search results which contain the characters in sequence

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4, select2-rails

I want to use `select2` search such that it also displays results which do not match the options strictly.

Eg. If `hello world` is present in the select box, typing `hl` or `hw` should return `hello world` as search result.

Answer (score 0):

The default `matcher` provided by Select2 does exact searches, but it can be extended to do custom matching.

A matcher like you are looking for can be found [at this pull request](https://github.com/select2/select2/pull/3653).

Comment: Does this modify the default matcher itself ?

Comment: I tried replacing `select2` repo with `https://github.com/vsevolodp/select2` repo. But it doesn't seem to work by default do I have to do something to make it work ?